# I need help installing Ubuntu on a Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So, a friend of mine want to have Ubuntu on his laptop **(acer aspire e5 575: 4gb ram, i3 7th gen, 1tb HDD)**.

**Here is the thing:** I don't know what partitions I'have to do in order to install Ubuntu Desktop (dual boot with W10). I already watched some tutorials, but I am now confused because all the tutorials show different installations methods. Some tutorials show this partitions: *root, boot, home, efi, swap*. This is where I'm lost. I don't want to mess up his laptop.

1. **P.S 1:** I already made the partition of the main disk (HDD) in Windows 10 (Disk Management) in order to have free space for Ubuntu
   (370gb of total free space)
2. **P.S 2:** I have Ubuntu Desktop as my main system as well. But I installed it on a new SDD, so other friend of mine told me that I
   only have to make this 3 partitions: *root, boot and home*. And this
   works totally perfect for me.
3. **P.S 3:** I'm new in GNU/Linux, so I don't have much idea of how file systems works here.
4. **P.S 4:** By the way, I hope that somebody can understand me because of my terrible english.

Comment: Don't make a `/boot` partition. That often leads to trouble when it fills up.

Comment: Keep it simple and let the installer do its job. It can create all the needed partitons automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First step, install Windows 10 on the entire disk - it is not necessary to make partitions because you can claim free space with Ubuntu installer if previously you did not make one partition.

When installing Ubuntu just select free space where it will reside and the installer will make necessary partitions for you. It's not that hard, trial and error.